# Confused about why something ran once but not another time

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I ran this code last night, and it worked fine it did plot the training loss as a fcn of epoch value. However, when I tried to run it today I changed the batch size from 1 to 8 and it gave me a 'plt not found' error. I then moved the plotting to below the matplotlib import line and it worked. This seems to suggest that line must come before the plotting, but how was I able to plot last night with the plot commands before the import?

This is just part of the complete code yes, but the rest wasn't relevant. This was in Jupyter notebook too, so perhaps I had ran the code before without the plot lines inside the tf.device block, and it saved the import or something?

```
with tf.device(device_name):

  inputx = Input(shape=(7,))
  x = Dense(4, activation='elu',name='x1')(inputx)
  x = Dense(16, activation='elu',name='x2')(x)
  x = Dense(25, activation='elu',name='x3')(x)
  x = Dense(10, activation='elu',name='x4')(x)
  xke = Dense(5,name='x5')(x)

  model = Model(inputx, xke)

        
  adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=1e-6, amsgrad=False)

     
  model.compile(optimizer=adam,
              loss=['mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error'],
              
              loss_weights=[1,1,1,1,1],) 
              
        
  model.summary()



  history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=30, verbose=1)

  plt.plot(history.history['loss'])

  plt.title('model loss')
  plt.ylabel('loss')
  plt.xlabel('epoch')
  plt.legend('train', loc='upper left')
  plt.show()  

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse
train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
train_rmse_sk = np.sqrt(mse(y_train, train_pred, multioutput= "raw_values"))
print("The training rmse value is: ", train_rmse_sk, "\n")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: always put your import statements at the top of your python file.

Comment: if it is in jupyter notebook, you would have already ran a cell with `import matplotlib as plt` before running that cell.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example! As it is your code depends an too many unknown variables.

Comment: @TomMcLean I do not have that statement anywhere else in my code, what I am thinking is I do have some plotting going on below the matplotlib statement in the code that is not shown in my post. Perhaps I ran this code which imported matplotlib, added the new plots code, and then reran it and it plotted. One interesting thing though is that with that logic, me running the code this morning should have worked just fine, UNLESS creating a new runtime gets rid of any saved history of what cells have been run. Do you know if that is true?

Comment: @TristanThomas something like that would have happened. Just move all of your imports to the top cell.

Comment: @TristanThomas,  if in a `jupyter notebook` or `interactive vscode`, then you only had to run it one in a cell at any point in time and it would be in memory until the kernel was stopped or restarted.